# Separate storage for ActiveMQ Scheduled/Delayed messages

Tags: java, database, activemq-classic

Recently we had to drop all the KahaDB files in order to get a production ActiveMQ server up and running. We waited for 45min but nothing showed up, so we were forced to drop all the info.

The pending messages were not an issue, but there were a number of scheduled jobs that requires rescheduling.

I was thinking, anticipating future similar situations, if it is possible to store that information in a differente storage, or maybe in a different KahaDB using mKahaDB?

Thanks

Carlos

Comment: I don't believe there is a built-in way. You can build your own plugin (http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html) and use that to intercept the appropriate messages and store them in a solution of your own. Of course you'd also have to hook into the startup process and replay these messages in the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I believe that, if you are forced to do so, maybe it's better to store these messages in a separate scheduler like Quartz, and let it handle the sending at the appropriate time, don't you think?

Comment: As I said, the storing is totally up to you. You would just have to ensure a proper replay.